# Amazon Gradle: Excluding JARs on build?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, compilation

I have an Amazon FirePhone project and for some reason it doesn't want to include the libraries that are part of the SDK in the editor. The symbols for all library packages are unresolved. When I click compile however, the project still compiles. (This also happens after a complete clean and rebuild)

If I include these libraries seperately in my own libs folder, they do get recognized. But when I do this the compilation process fails under the guise of 'duplicate AndroidManifest.xml'.

Is there a way (using the Gradle Android plugin) to include the JAR's in the project, but exclude them when building the project? This way I'd still get the class references in my editor without getting duplicate conflicts due to the build process including both my lib files and the ones in the SDK.